# updating a multidimensional array stored in session storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have taken over a project and am not totally familiar with JQuery and session storage. The issue is that after updating the info and clicking update it provides an error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
        `at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at fillArray (main.js? [sm]:313)
        at UpdateProduct (main.js? [sm]:234)
        at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):405)".`

Included link to github repo:https://github.com/bveasey/Jquery-project

```
function UpdateProduct() // called on click of an update btn
{

   // capture id from hidden element set in editproduct function
   var productId = $('#txtHiddenId').val();
   console.log("***** line:233 *****\n product id =" + productId);
   fillArray(productId);
   console.log("***** line:235 *****\n Fill array called!");
   BindTable();
   console.log("***** line:237 *****\n Bind Table called!");
}

// other functions 
function fillArray(prodid)
{
  console.log("***** line:310 *****\n  Begin Fill Array");

  // find the item in the product array and update it
  $.each(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.setItem('products', 
  JSON.stringify(productArray))), function (idx, v) 
{
  console.log("***** line:315 *****\n " + product.id);
  // Check if current prodid is the id wanted
  if (product.id === prodid) 
  {// ids match
    console.log("***** line:319 *****\n product is's match");

    // populate data
    product.id = productId;
    product.arrivalDate = $('#modalRequestedArrivalDate').val();
    product.productCode = $('#modalProductCode').val();
    product.description = $('#modalDescription').val();
    product.quantity = $('#modalQuantity').val();
    product.quantityType = $('#modalQuantityType').val();
    product.plant = $('#modalPlant').val();
    product.shippingMethod = $('#modalShippingMethod').val();
    product.specialInstructions = $('#modalSpecialInstructions').val();

    console.log("***** line:310 *****\n  END Fill Array");
  }
});
```

}
   // bind table just updates the table.

Comment: What is `productArray`? Where is it set?

Answer (score 0):

[`Storage#setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) returns `void`, you can't parse `void` using `JSON.parse()`, `void` is not valid JSON syntax.

The Error tells you exactly where the problematic code is,

```
 $.each(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(productArray))), function (idx, v)...
```

The `sessionStorage.setItem()` here doesn't return anything that the `JSON.parse()` can parse.